# R greater than or equal to character converts to equal sign

Tags: r, text, encoding, character-encoding

I have imported an Excel (xlsx) file using the `readxl` package in `R`.  One of the columns, `labeldata`, that is imported into `R` contains labels for other data contained in the file, so it consists of character data such as `≥65 years old`.  When I print this `labeldata` to the console the value for "greater than or equal to 65 years old"
 is properly displayed as `≥65 years old`.  However, when I try to combine this column with other columns (using `cbind` or other methods), the greater than or equal to sign (`≥`) is converted to an equal sign (`=`).  I tried to `dput` the `labeldata` object to a text file, to include in this post, but when I do so, the greater than or equal sign is converted to an equal sign there as well.

Here's the best toy example I can come up with that kind of explains what I'm seeing:

```
labeldata="≥ 65 years"
print(labeldata)
[1] "= 65 years"
```

The problem with this example, of course, is that I've simply *typed* in the label and could avoid the conversion issue by typing in `labeldata="\u2265 65 years"`, but in my real work, I'm not typing in this infomration, but importing the data from Excel.

I'm guessing this is some sort of encoding issue, but **is there any way to prevent the label from converting to an equal sign and to preserve the original label?**

**Updated relevant information**

I am using Windows 10 x64 OS, with R Studio, but I've verified the problem exists within just R.  I have this problem in R 3.2.3 and R 3.6.1.

I've also noticed that while this works without any problem:

```
labeldata = "\u2265 65 years"
labeldata
[1] "≥ 65 years"
```

Converting to a dataframe causes the problem to reappear:

```
labeldata = "\u2265 65 years"
labeldata
[1] "≥ 65 years"
data.frame(labeldata)
labeldata
1 = 65 years
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, with me it prints `[1] "≥ 65 years"`. And why `rep`? `c()` or, in the case of just one string, no function call, `labeldata = "≥ 65 years"` would do it. See the help page `?rep`.

Comment: Same, have been testing and can't get to reproduce either.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, sorry for the rep.  That was a mistake left over from making a toy example (I've deleted "rep" in my code above).  I'm not sure if it's relevant or not, but I'm using R studio Version 1.2.1568 with R  3.6.1.

Comment: Updating my previous comment.  I can confirm that this behavior also exists in just R, with R version 3.2.3, so I think I can rule out RStudio.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it seems that this problem is avoided by converting the vector to a dployr tbl.

Comment: I'll counter to @RuiBarradas and @caldwellst, and confirm that i can reproduce the error while running Windows 10 (up-to-date), R-3.6.1 build 17134 on a clean session. This happens in both `R` and `R-studio`, and as such is not restricted to a single IDE.

Comment: @Oliver OK, I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, so maybe that's why I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 here. I can't reproduce the problem. The symbol is properly displayed in both R and RStudio. Could it be a windows problem?

Comment: The fact that I can avoid the problem by using `dplyr`'s `tbl_df` in Windows, along with the other reports here, makes me think there's something going on with base `R` for Windows.